# Ruby modifying methods at runtime from modules

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have `my_class` which contains `my_method` with behaviour A. In `my_module` I have the same method with behaviour B.

Wanting to dynamically modify the behaviour of `my_class`, I am trying to use metaprogramming to change the methods at runtime.

How could I make `my_class` have behaviour A, then change it to behaviour AB, or B, then back to A ?

I wanted to keep the source code of previous versions in a history array so that I would be able to retrieve the old version and restore it, but another thread told me that we cannot just get methods' source code.

Small example :

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

module World
  def my_method
    puts " World !"
  end
end
```

Then, at runtime I could call my_method, the result being "Hello", then make the method from the module extend the method and it would print "Hello World !" (on two lines, that's not the point, I do not seek to "merge" them)

Comment: `alias_method` might be what you are looking for or maybe `super` your question is a bit unclear

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? "dynamically" modifying a methods behavior (and then restore the original version) sounds like something you want to avoid.

Comment: This does not relate to any problem. I am new to ruby's metaprogramming and want to learn how to do this. Alias seems promising but how could I still execute the old method behavior (and could I use a special keyword to trigger the old method behavior so that I could execute the old code wherever I want in the new one)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use extension, but I think it gets closer to what your after:

```rb
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @nodes = []
    @nodes.push( ->() {"hello 0"})
    @nodes.push( ->() {"hello 1"})
    @nodes.push( ->() {"hello 2"})
  end

  def my_method(version = 0)
    @nodes[version].call
  end
end

my_instance = MyHelloClass.new
my_instance.my_method
#=> 'hello 0'
my_instance.my_method(1)
#=> 'hello 1'
my_instance.my_method(2)
#=> 'hello 2'
```

Comment: In terms of goal, yes, plus the ability to revert back to the simple "hello". But I don't think this is what I am looking for. I don't want to simply add parameters or one instruction. I would like to add the instructions inside the module's method inside the class' method. In essence, a bit as if my local code was a git and at runtime I could "commit" new code in functions and go back to the previous version when needed.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand. Can you give an example of how you'd like to be able to reference these different psudo-branches?

Comment: Great ! So I was thinking about a linked list where the first node is the base method (inside the class), then everytime you "add" a module (here MyWorldModule), a new node is created. The call to the method would only call the one on the last node (LIFO), but with a keyword I could call the method from the previous node. Ideally this would work for an unknown amount of nodes where each node could execute its own code, then the code from the previous node if requested (or before, depending on the place of the special keyword).

Comment: Does that get us closer? I think lambdas might be a better route for this functionality. Then you can manage a simple array rather than a hierarchy of classes. And if you wanted keywords instead of indexes, you could replace the array with a hash.

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly what I want to achieve, but I'll work with it. I'm trying to use the same method call. Anyway, It does give me some hindsight. Thank you for your time

Comment: Good. Let me know if there is any way I can change my answer to get an up-vote. Also, in your journey to solve this problem, you may want to look at 'define_method', 'method_missing' and the 'Class.ancestors' methods. They are critical in starting to look into ruby meta programming. Good luck!